# Parsing HTML 5 anchor tag with Tagsoup Parser

Tags: html, sax, tag-soup

I am using tagsoup Parser which follows HTML4 and doesn't allow a `<p>` tag inside an `<a>` tag. Because of this,it is parsing incorrect HTML.
I went through tagsoup docs but couldn't find any useful information through which tagsoup (org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup) can be configured to use HTML5 standards.
e.g

```
<a href="/foreign-education-exam"><p >Study Abroad</p></a>
```

becomes

```
<a shape="rect" href="/foreign-education-exam" /><p>Study Abroad</p>
```

Comment: I am still struggling to find a solution for this.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Generally according to W3c standard you cannot make any p tag under a anchor tag.So because of that reason it might be converting your code.

Instead of **p** tag make use of **span** tag it will work for you sure.

Comment: <p> tag is just an example.Basically it can be <div> also . The website which i want to parse is full of such scenarios,so basically it is near to impossible to make changes every where